# Concatenate each line of 2 text files

Tags: string, vbscript, batch-file, string-concatenation

File1.txt is:

```
Abcd
Efghhh
Ijkl
+1000 other lines
```

File2.txt is:

```
1234
1368
QL23372
+1000 other lines
```

I want to create File3.txt containing:

```
Abcd$1234
Efghhh$1368
Ijkl$QL23372
+1000 other lines
```

How to do this in batch or VBscript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using *.bat file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in (file1.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set arr1[!i!]=%%A
)

set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%A in (file2.txt) do (
    set /A i+=1
    set arr2[!i!]=%%A
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do @echo !arr1[%%i]!$!arr2[%%i]!>> result.txt
```

Comment: This does not preserve blank lines, it corrupts lines with ! in them.  These two limitations are known problems with this style of solution but should be mentioned so that readers can choose if the solution it suits them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming equal number of lines for both files:

```
string[] lines1 = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt");
string[] lines2 = File.ReadAllLines("File2.txt");

string[] lines3 = new string[lines1.Length];
for(int i=0;i<lines1.Length;i++)
    lines3[i]=lines1[i]+"$"+lines2[i];
File.WriteAllLines("File3.txt",lines3);
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I compile/run it with the most simplest way? (i'm only used to batch, vbscript or traditionnal C with a C compiler)

Comment: Create a new Windows Forms project, drag a button from the Toolbox, double click it, and paste this code. Make sure the files are in the same folder with the exe file; or use absolute file paths. Then hit F5 to run and click the button.

Comment: What do I need to have? Visual Studio? Or something else? What's the lightest solution?

Comment: I use Visual Studio.NET, but you can use any c# compiler

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Read File1.txt with SET /P command via standard input
< File1.txt (
   rem Read File2.txt with FOR command
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (File2.txt) do (
      set /P line1=
      echo !line1!$%%a
   )
rem Send output to File3.txt
) > File3.txt
```

This Batch program will fail if the input files contain empty lines. It also will fail with special Batch characters, like `! < | >`. These limitations may be fixed, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

A VBScript attempt:

```
  Dim oFS   : Set oFS   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim tsFst : Set tsFst = oFS.OpenTextFile("M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\filezipper\fst")
  Dim tsSnd : Set tsSnd = oFS.OpenTextFile("M:\lib\kurs0705\testdata\filezipper\snd")
  Do Until tsFst.AtEndOfStream Or tsSnd.AtEndOfStream
     WScript.Echo tsFst.ReadLine() & "$" & tsSnd.ReadLine()
  Loop
  tsSnd.Close
  tsFst.Close
```

that avoids extra arrays.